# Add pointer to defined Objective-C class in .h file of Objective-C++

Tags: c++, objective-c, macos, objective-c++, cross-language

Is possible to create class in Objective-C++ which has field that is a pointer to an Objective-C interface ( inside the `.h` file ) ?

To clarify a little, I created one Objective-C interface:

```
// Our platform independent class
@interface LoggerDelegate : NSObject<SomeDelegate>
@end
```

I can create it inside `.mm` file and it works but it is meant for a global variable and I am not allowed to change its scope. So I would like to use it inside `Logger.h`:

```
class Logger {
public:

private:

LoggerDelegate* _ptr;   //<--- pointer to the Objective-C interface
};
```

When I define my interface inside `Logger.mm` it works. But is it possible to merge in Objective-C++ code from Objective-C and C++ inside `.h` files ? Or is it only possible in `.mm` files ?

Comment: Short answer: Only possible in .mm files. This is because Objective-C has no idea what `class`, `public`, `private` is (C++)..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### The language family

[**Objective-C**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objective-C) uses `.h` headers and `.m` implementation files.  You may not need the latter in case of an abstract interface.  All these files have to comply with the Objective-C syntax:

- you may use some C syntax in the `.h` or `.m`; it will be recognized, because Objective C is a language extension of C.
- pure C++ language elements (e.g. `class` or `template`) will not be recognized by the Objective-C compiler.

[**Objective-C++**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objective-C#Objective-C.2B.2B) uses also `.h` headers but `.mm` implementation files.  Both have to comply with the Objective-C++ syntax:

- Most of the C++ syntax will be recognized, because Objective C++ is based on C++.
- All the Objective-C syntax will be recognized because Objective C is a subset of Objective-C++.

[**Standard C++**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B) uses headers (usually `.h` or `.hpp`) and implementation files (usually `.cc` or `.cpp`).  These must use only C++ language elements.  Objective-C and Objective-C++ language elements that do not belong to C++, such as for example `@interface` will trigger C++ compilation errors.

### Mixing the languages - syntax problems

**Mixing Objective-C and Objective-C++:** If you share the headers  (`.h`) between Objective-C and Objective C++, they will have to comply with both Objective-C and Objective-C++.  In consequence, the header can use only the common denominator between the two languages, that is Objective-C (and C) language elements.

**Mixing standard C++ and objective C/C++**: You can combine C++ language with Objective-C or Objective-C++ constructs only in Objective-C++ (so `.mm` files, and eventually `.h` if and only if not included in any standard C++ or Objective-C source code)

THis is why you may use your Objective-C interface in a `.mm` file.  But  you can't use it in a `.h` file that would be included in C++ code.

### Mixing the languages - sematic problems

The object model and lifecycle of standard C++ and the Objective-C/C++ are not the same.  This makes interoperability difficult.  For example a C++ class can't inherit from an Objective-C class, and if an Objective-C class contains a C++ object the [construction](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/interoperating-between-c-and-objective-c/240165502) can be tricky. And there is no C++ language construct that would be guaranteed to be natively compatible with the Objective-C++ `@interface` either.

### But isn't there a way to interoperate with pointers ?

It is possible to manage pointers from C++ to Objective-C++ objects by using the [PIMPL idiom](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pimpl) (also called "the opaque pointer"). [This brilliant article from Phil Jordan](http://philjordan.eu/article/mixing-objective-c-c++-and-objective-c++) explains how to do this with an example that you could easily reuse.

Phil Jordan's main idea is to use a header to wrap the Objective-C++ object into a standard C++ class using a pointer to an incomplete object.  Phil uses conditional compilation in a clever way to allow the use of the same `.h` for cross-language purpose:

```
#ifdef __OBJC__
@class XXXX;       // if header used in Objective C++
#else
struct XXXX;        // if header used in standard C++
#endif

class WrapperClass {   // standard C++ class also recognuzed by Objective C++
    XXXX *wrapped_objective_c_object_pointer; 
public:  
    ...// public interface for C++
};
```

This ensures that C++ code that includes the header can never use the pointer to perform any operation on the wrapped object.  The implementation of the C++ wrapper class will then be provided in a `.mm` file, which is aware of the Objective C++ semantic.  I strongly recommend that you read the article to understand all the details of that solution.

Comment: Could you talk a bit about using structs between languages? For example if I define a struct in a .h `c` file should I then be able to use it across code of all c based types?

Comment: @J.Doe the logic stays true:  You can define a C struct  in a .h header. and use it in also in Objective C.  However it must be a plain old C structure.  The C++ struct, which are in fact a special kind of classes and can hence have constructors and member functions won't be understood in Objective C