# Using C++ in Swift

Tags: c++, objective-c, swift, macos

The problem is that I don't what to write C code. I have some libraries - for example for building suffix automaton for a given text and it is much more comfortable to write this with C++. Then I want to write swift app with such class, but how to do it without writing C code and without some restrictions on using C++ code. For example 
in my test.cpp I have

```
#include "test.h"
#include <string>

std::string hello() {
 return "Hello";
}
```

In my bridge I have:

```
#include "test.h"
```

But there is problems with test.h.
Without using C I can't just write

```
#include <string>
std::string hello();
```

Comment: You *cannot* call C++ code from Swift, see for example https://stackoverflow.com/q/35229149/1187415 or https://stackoverflow.com/q/48971931/1187415.

Comment: You have two choices:  Objective-C++ with which you use the Objective-C part to bridge Swift to Objective-C to Objective-C++ to the C++ part, or a C thunking layer that bridges from Swift to C to C++.

Comment: C++ is, for most practical purposes, a superset of C.  So, if you are comfortable with C++, you should be comfortable with C.  I agree with the 2 earlier comments.  If you run into specific problems, don't hesitate to come up with simple reproducible examples that demonstrate them, and people here will probably help you out.